# Cannot open database "Transport1" requested by the login

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I make Myself application (I use MVC5/EF6) under the tutorial
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
I have a folder DAL two classes (TransportContext.cs and TransportInitializer.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TrueSite.Models;

namespace TrueSite.DAL
{
    public class TransportContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Package> Packages {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Message> Messages {get; set;}
        public TransportContext() : base("TransportContext")
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Initializer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TrueSite.Models;

namespace TrueSite.DAL
{
    public class TransportInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TransportContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TransportContext context)
        {
            var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User{FirstName="John", LastName="Black", Age=22, RegisterDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-02-09")},
                new User{FirstName="Jack", LastName="AndChan", Age=22, RegisterDate=DateTime.Parse("2011-02-08")},
                new User{FirstName="Mike", LastName="Yellow", Age=32, RegisterDate=DateTime.Parse("2012-01-01")}
            };
            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            var packages = new List<Package>
            {
                new Package{Name="Sand", Status=STATUS.SUCCESS, From="Poland", To="Poland", Date=DateTime.Parse("2011-01-11 00:10"), Weight=10.00, UserID = 1},
                new Package{Name="People", Status=STATUS.FAIL, From="Africa", To="Poland", Date=DateTime.Parse("2015-02-12 10:09"), Weight=80.98, UserID = 1},
                new Package{Name="AK-47", Status=STATUS.ACTIVE, From="France", To="Poland", Weight=7.00, UserID = 1},
                new Package{Name="PC", Status=STATUS.WAIT, From="Russia", To="Poland", Date=DateTime.Parse("2015-03-25 10:09"), Weight=9.00, UserID = 1}
            };
            packages.ForEach(s => context.Packages.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            var messages = new List<Message>
            {
                new Message{Title="Your parcel will not be delivered", Text="Package number 2 will not be delivered because it is incompatible with human rights", UserID=1},
                new Message{Title="Your shipment was delivered", Text="Parcel number 3 gets delayed because the courier sick", UserID = 1},
                new Message{Title="Your parcel will be delivered with a delay", Text="Package number 4 was delivered during your absence, waiting for pick up at the post office", UserID=1}
            };
            messages.ForEach(s => context.Messages.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
}
```

Everything has been compiled , but the database is not created

> Cannot open database "Transport1" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Familly\Camil'.

My Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TransportContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Transport1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
    <context type="TrueSite.DAL.TransportContext, TrueSite">
      <databaseInitializer type="TrueSite.DAL.TransportInitializer, TrueSite" />
    </context>
  </contexts>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My models: Message.cs, Package.cs and User.cs

Message.cs

```
 public class Message
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text;
        public string From { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    }
```

Package.cs

```
   public enum STATUS
    {
        SUCCESS,
        FAIL,
        ACTIVE,
        WAIT,
        WAITCOURIER
    }
    public class Package
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public STATUS? Status { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
    }
```

User.cs

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public byte Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public bool service { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TransportContext class constructor needs to have the exact name of the connectionString

```
public TransportContext() : base("TransportContext")
{
}
```

Make sure you set up the database initializer in the web.config file within the entityframework xml tags so that database is created when the application first runs.

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="TrueSite.DAL.TransportContext , TrueSite">
      <databaseInitializer type="TrueSite.DAL.TransportInitializer , TrueSite" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

**Update**

Ok then it would seem to be a login issue you should try these steps.

1) Open SQL Server Management Studio

2) In the "Connect to Server" window (File->Connect object explorer) enter the following:

- Server type    : Database Engine
- Server name    : (localdb)\v11.0
- Authentication : [Whatever you used when you created your local db. Probably Windows Authentication).

3) Click "Connect"

4) Expand the "Databases" folder in the Object Explorer (View->Object Explorer, F8)

5) Find your database. It should be named as the full path to your database (.mdf) file

- You should see it says "(Pending Recovery)" at the end of the database name or when you try to expand the database it won't be able to and may or may not give you an error message.
- This the issue! Your database has crashed essentially..

6) Right click on the database then select "Tasks -> Detach...".

7) In the detach window, select your database in the list and check the column that says "Drop Connections"

8) Click OK.

9) You should see the database disappear from the list of databases. Your problem should now be fixed. Go and run your application that uses your localdb.

10) After running your application, your database will re-appear in the list of databases - this is correct. It should not say "Pending recovery" any more since it should be working properly.

Comment: There is no ... My database

Comment: @MyName I don't understand what you mean in your latest comment.

Comment: In the fifth step is not my base

Comment: @MyName then you will want to go through the process of adding a localdb https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I updated the first post with the code models. I created a database as it was written there, but no table you want to create when compiling